# Self calculated RGB values aren't matching with actual RGB values

Tags: java, colors, rgb

I am working on a program where I take a portion of an image and calculate the average RGB of that image. When I calculate it I get totally different values as if I was to use the built in function. When I test my numbers and put them in an RGB color chart they are off while the built in function is very accurate. The problem with using the built in function is that it has literally no functionality. It just prints out what I calculate but I can't use that data. [link to function called dump()](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/core/Mat.html)

```
public void readSquares(Mat img){

    int width = 20;
    int height = 20;
    int rSum = 0;
    int gSum = 0;
    int bSum = 0;
    int rAvg = 0;
    int gAvg = 0;
    int bAvg = 0;

    Imgproc.cvtColor(img, img, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGB);   
    int channels = img.channels();

    int totalBytes = (int)(img.total() * img.channels());

    byte buff[] = new byte[totalBytes];
    img.get(0, 0, buff);

    for (int i=0; i< height; i++) {
        //stride is the number of bytes in a row of smallImg
        int stride = channels * width;
        for (int j=0; j<stride; j+=channels) {
            int r = buff[(i * stride) + j];
            int g = buff[(i * stride) + j + 1]; 
            int b = buff[(i * stride) + j + 2];

            if(r < 0 || g < 0 || b < 0){
                r = Math.abs(r);
                g = Math.abs(g);
                b = Math.abs(b);    
            }

            rSum += r;
            gSum += g;
            bSum += b;

        }
    }   

    rAvg = (int) (rSum / img.total()); //total pixels in picture
    gAvg = (int) (gSum / img.total());
    bAvg = (int) (bSum / img.total());
    System.out.println("R: " + rAvg);
    System.out.println("G: " + gAvg);
    System.out.println("B: " + bAvg);
```

This below prints out the accurate values but I can't get the separate channels or find the average RGB it just spits everything out as a string which I can't utilize.

```
System.out.println(img.dump());
}
```

Here is an example; I read Red image for pixels this was the output:

**My Calculated**

```
R:18
G:27
B:64
```

**The function**
The first number represents the R second the G and third the B. It does that for every pixel in the image.

```
[237,  24,  60, 236,  23,  59, 236,  26,  56, 234,  25,  55, 238,  27,  62, 238,  27,  62, 238,  27,  62, 236,  25,  60, 234,  24,  59, 233,  23,  57, 234,  24,  59, 234,  24,  59, 235,  22,  59, 235,  22,  59, 237,  21,  59, 235,  20,  58, 237,  19,  56, 237,  19,  56, 239,  19,  52, 237,  18,  51;
 236,  24,  55, 237,  25,  56, 237,  25,  54, 237,  25,  54, 236,  26,  56, 237,  27,  57, 238,  28,  58, 239,  29,  59, 238,  27,  62, 234,  24,  59, 237,  24,  62, 237,  24,  62, 238,  22,  63, 237,  20,  61, 235,  20,  58, 235,  20,  58, 237,  19,  58, 239,  21,  61, 237,  19,  56, 236,  18,  55;
 238,  26,  57, 238,  26,  57, 234,  25,  53, 232,  23,  50, 236,  26,  54, 237,  27,  55, 237,  27,  55, 237,  27,  55, 237,  26,  61, 236,  25,  60, 237,  24,  62, 237,  24,  62, 238,  22,  63, 237,  20,  61, 238,  22,  63, 238,  22,  63, 238,  20,  61, 238,  20,  61, 237,  19,  56, 236,  18,  55;
 242,  30,  60, 240,  27,  58, 235,  24,  49, 233,  21,  47, 234,  22,  48, 237,  26,  52, 236,  25,  50, 237,  26,  52, 238,  26,  57, 237,  25,  56, 239,  23,  62, 239,  23,  62, 238,  22,  63, 238,  22,  63, 238,  19,  63, 239,  20,  65, 238,  20,  61, 239,  21,  63, 238,  20,  59, 236,  18,  57;
 240,  27,  62, 236,  23,  59, 236,  24,  53, 236,  24,  53, 235,  23,  51, 234,  22,  50, 235,  23,  51, 236,  24,  53, 237,  24,  60, 236,  23,  59, 237,  24,  64, 237,  24,  64, 237,  24,  64, 236,  22,  63, 238,  22,  63, 238,  22,  63, 237,  20,  61, 237,  20,  61, 237,  21,  59, 235,  20,  58;
 238,  25,  61, 237,  24,  60, 237,  24,  60, 237,  24,  60, 235,  22,  57, 236,  23,  59, 235,  22,  57, 235,  22,  57, 234,  21,  56, 236,  23,  59, 237,  24,  62, 236,  23,  61, 237,  20,  61, 237,  20,  61, 238,  21,  65, 238,  21,  65, 238,  22,  63, 237,  20,  61, 235,  22,  59, 235,  22,  59;
 238,  27,  62, 237,  26,  61, 237,  24,  60, 236,  23,  59, 236,  24,  55, 236,  24,  55, 236,  24,  55, 234,  22,  52, 237,  22,  53, 237,  22,  53, 237,  21,  57, 237,  21,  57, 237,  21,  59, 237,  21,  59, 237,  20,  61, 237,  20,  61, 236,  22,  63, 236,  22,  63, 236,  22,  63, 235,  21,  61;
 237,  26,  63, 236,  25,  62, 237,  24,  62, 237,  24,  62, 238,  25,  63, 237,  24,  62, 237,  21,  57, 238,  22,  59, 237,  21,  57, 237,  21,  57, 235,  20,  56, 235,  20,  56, 235,  20,  56, 237,  21,  57, 237,  21,  57, 238,  22,  59, 235,  23,  53, 236,  24,  55, 236,  24,  53, 236,  24,  53;
 236,  29,  69, 235,  28,  68, 238,  26,  70, 239,  27,  71, 240,  25,  68, 238,  24,  67, 237,  24,  64, 236,  22,  63, 237,  20,  61, 235,  19,  60, 237,  19,  58, 236,  18,  57, 237,  21,  59, 237,  21,  59, 238,  22,  59, 240,  25,  61, 237,  25,  56, 236,  24,  55, 236,  24,  53, 237,  25,  54;
 235,  28,  66, 235,  28,  66, 237,  25,  65, 240,  29,  68, 241,  27,  67, 238,  25,  65, 239,  23,  64, 238,  22,  63, 237,  19,  58, 237,  19,  58, 237,  17,  57, 237,  17,  57, 240,  20,  57, 241,  21,  59, 238,  21,  53, 239,  22,  55, 240,  26,  55, 238,  23,  53, 237,  22,  51, 237,  22,  51;
 237,  25,  69, 237,  25,  69, 239,  27,  73, 239,  27,  73, 240,  25,  70, 241,  26,  71, 239,  22,  66, 237,  20,  63, 238,  20,  61, 237,  18,  60, 236,  17,  59, 237,  18,  60, 238,  20,  59, 239,  21,  61, 238,  22,  59, 238,  22,  59, 239,  25,  54, 237,  22,  51, 237,  23,  49, 235,  22,  48;
 237,  25,  65, 238,  27,  66, 238,  27,  66, 238,  27,  66, 238,  27,  66, 237,  25,  65, 236,  22,  63, 235,  21,  61, 235,  22,  59, 235,  22,  59, 234,  18,  57, 237,  21,  59, 238,  22,  61, 238,  22,  61, 238,  22,  59, 238,  22,  59, 238,  20,  57, 238,  20,  57, 237,  20,  52, 237,  20,  52;
 236,  25,  60, 236,  25,  60, 238,  27,  62, 239,  29,  63, 237,  26,  61, 236,  25,  60, 237,  26,  61, 236,  25,  60, 236,  23,  59, 235,  22,  57, 236,  23,  59, 235,  22,  57, 237,  24,  60, 236,  23,  59, 238,  22,  59, 237,  21,  57, 237,  21,  57, 235,  20,  56, 236,  18,  55, 235,  17,  54;
 237,  25,  56, 238,  26,  57, 237,  27,  57, 237,  27,  57, 236,  26,  56, 237,  27,  57, 238,  28,  58, 237,  27,  57, 237,  27,  57, 238,  28,  58, 240,  27,  58, 237,  25,  56, 236,  23,  59, 236,  23,  59, 237,  21,  57, 237,  21,  57, 235,  20,  58, 235,  20,  58, 236,  18,  55, 236,  18,  55;
 237,  25,  54, 237,  25,  54, 237,  25,  54, 235,  23,  51, 237,  25,  56, 240,  27,  58, 237,  26,  61, 236,  25,  60, 237,  26,  63, 237,  26,  63, 238,  27,  66, 236,  24,  64, 237,  24,  64, 236,  22,  63, 237,  20,  61, 235,  19,  60, 236,  17,  59, 236,  17,  59, 236,  18,  57, 235,  16,  56;
 237,  25,  56, 237,  25,  56, 236,  23,  59, 238,  25,  61, 237,  24,  62, 238,  25,  63, 237,  24,  64, 238,  25,  65, 240,  25,  68, 238,  24,  67, 237,  23,  66, 237,  23,  66, 238,  21,  65, 238,  21,  65, 237,  20,  63, 237,  20,  63, 235,  19,  62, 235,  19,  62, 235,  19,  60, 235,  19,  60;
 237,  25,  56, 237,  25,  56, 237,  24,  60, 237,  24,  60, 237,  24,  64, 234,  20,  60, 237,  23,  66, 238,  24,  67, 238,  24,  69, 237,  23,  68, 236,  23,  70, 234,  22,  69, 236,  22,  67, 233,  18,  63, 236,  22,  65, 235,  21,  63, 236,  22,  63, 234,  20,  60, 235,  22,  59, 235,  22,  59;
 238,  27,  55, 238,  27,  55, 239,  24,  56, 241,  27,  58, 237,  24,  62, 237,  24,  62, 237,  23,  66, 238,  24,  67, 237,  24,  71, 237,  24,  71, 236,  23,  72, 234,  22,  71, 231,  19,  65, 236,  23,  70, 236,  24,  68, 236,  24,  68, 237,  24,  62, 236,  23,  61, 236,  24,  55, 238,  26,  57;
 239,  29,  63, 236,  25,  60, 236,  25,  62, 236,  25,  62, 236,  24,  64, 237,  25,  65, 234,  27,  67, 232,  26,  66, 238,  31,  74, 236,  29,  71, 234,  26,  71, 231,  24,  69, 232,  25,  70, 234,  26,  71, 236,  29,  71, 238,  31,  74, 235,  28,  68, 232,  26,  66, 237,  26,  63, 236,  25,  62;
 237,  24,  60, 237,  24,  60, 237,  26,  61, 236,  25,  60, 233,  22,  59, 234,  24,  61, 232,  26,  62, 234,  28,  63, 234,  27,  65, 234,  27,  65, 234,  26,  69, 234,  26,  69, 234,  26,  73, 234,  26,  73, 237,  29,  79, 238,  30,  80, 236,  29,  71, 234,  26,  69, 237,  26,  63, 238,  27,  64]
```

Comment: The values are correct. What you don't realize is that you are using signed bytes which means all the red values above 127 are negative. 240 becomes -15 etc. Then you take to absolute and average those. That's probably not what you want. Convert to unsigned and average those. A simple debugging session would've shown you immediately what is happening with the values.

Comment: how would I convert them to unsigned bytes? @SamiKuhmonen

Comment: what would I do to my conversion? @SamiKuhmonen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the Java Language Specification states that a byte data type has the range −128 - 127 and that's how Java will interpret a byte. If for instance a byte is promoted or cast to an int Java will interpret the first bit as a sign and use sign extension. There's no language support to help you interpret a byte differently. (There's, for instance, no unsigned keyword in Java.)

That being said, nothing prevents you from viewing a byte as an 8-bit value and interpret those bits as unsigned. Just keep in mind that there's nothing you can do to force your interpretation upon someone else's method. If a method accepts a byte, then that method accepts a value between −128 and 127 unless explicitly stated otherwise.

```
    public static int unsignedToBytes(byte b) {
        return b & 0xFF;
    }
```

This method does what you asked. Hope this helps !!!

Edit: There are plenty of good answers on Stack Overflow and elsewhere. I would recommend you to try finding the answer before posting the question. Thanks.